# How to make a heatmap contour plot using three 2D arrays?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

So I've seen examples where you have two 1D arrays and use a meshgrid then just use the two values from that and your z array to create the contour. But I have 3 inherently 2D arrays that I need for a contour, but so far this is what is being displayed. Any ideas? (Ignore the dummy variable names) Photo and code as listed:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Cp1.png)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
     
contourOne = ax1.contourf(data,data2, np.log(data3))
ax1.set_title("title")
ax1.set_xlabel("idk")
ax1.set_ylabel("idk")
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(contourOne, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')


contourTwo = ax2.contourf(data4,data5, np.log(data6))
ax2.set_title("title")
ax2.set_xlabel("idk")
ax2.set_ylabel("idk")
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(contourTwo, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')

#Set graph spacing and show graphs
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4,hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You might try a tricontourf: `ax1.tricontourf(data.ravel(), data2.ravel(), np.log(data3.ravel()))`. Anyway, without knowing how the data is organized, it's hard to know what's going on.

Comment: @JohanC So I tried that and I got the error "z array must not contain non-finite values within the triangulation". Also what would you like to know about the data, I don't really think how it was made is as important, but all the arrays of data are 2500x487

Comment: @JohanC I don't believe it has any negative or 0 values, though that's a good point I didn't consider before. Is contourf capable of taking in 3 arguments in the first place? I would absolutely believe so but I'm just not sure if it can with 3 2D arrays, do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: `tricontourf` creates its own triangulation, unlike `contourf` which supposes its input is organized as a nice grid. That's why `tricontourf` needs the `ravel` to convert the arrays to 1D.  `contourf` works with one or three 2D arrays. You could try to leave out the first two. But, as mentioned before, very hard to give advise without knowing how the arrays are organized.

Comment: @JohanC Oh okay I see, thanks for the explanation. The contour did work with just the log of the array, but not with all 3. Also what do you mean by how they are organized? Perhaps I can provide some more information for you

Comment: You could try `ax1.scatter(data.ravel(), data2.ravel(), c=np.log(data3.ravel()))` to see whether the data make sense. Or `ax1.scatter(data.ravel(), data2.ravel(), c=np.linspace(0,1,data.size))`  to get an idea about how the data is organized.